# Canvas HTML5 JS drawImage z-index

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i need help, i'm creating the city map for a game, i created this script that retrieves the information through an array to the order of the structures but i can not highlight the structures, i appear overlapped, i would put one Z-Index But i don't know how to do it, help me.

```
var Canvas_Image_Arr = [{"name":"NAME1","Image":"../structure1.png","x":"439","y":"47","z":"3","w":"175","h":"179"},{"name":"NAME2","Image":"../structure2.png","x":"554","y":"175","z":"2","w":"175","h":"179"}];

window.onload = function(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("ctymap");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.canvas.width = 942;
ctx.canvas.height = 430;

canvas.style.background = "url(../background.jpg)";

Canvas_Image_Arr.forEach(function(element){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = element.Image;
    this.zIndex = element.z;
    img.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(this, element.x, element.y, this.width, this.height);
    }

});
}
```

On the array  "CANVAS_IMAGE_ARR " i created an entry called Z for the layer, as i create the level of each individual drawImage?

Comment: Canvas doesn't use z-layering, it just goes by order of drawing. One simple solution might be to sort `Canvas_Image_Arr` by `z` before drawing

Comment: Hamms comment in a different way: Canvas output in the browser is a rasterized, flat image without layering.

Comment: Your problem is that you are drawing your images individually as soon as they load. You can't be sure of their loading order. So to circumvent this, wait that all your assets have loaded before drawing anything on your canvas. You should have an init function somewhere that gets triggered on assets load. And **never** load a new image after this init has been called.

Answer (score 0):

## Render ontop

The fastest way is to use two canvases. One holds the whole image and is kept off-screen, the other is the display canvas.

You render the images to the off-screen canvas as normal. Then when the image is ready you clear the onscreen canvas, draw the off-screen canvas onto that, then draw the highlighted item on top of that.

This saves you having to sort and redraw all the images just to bring one to the top.

### Example

The demo shows this done. Rather than find a pile of images I create images via the canvas. The code of interest is just the top function `displayLoop` When needed it finds the closest image to the mouse, If that is a new image clears the canvas, draws the `offScreen` canvas, and then the nearest image on top.

**Note:** this method will increase the edge contrast a little for some images.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(displayLoop);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvents);
const numImages = 100;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const offScreen = createImage(512,true);
const offCtx = offScreen.getContext("2d");


var lastImage;
function displayLoop(){
   if (images.length === 0) { createAllImages() }
   if (mouse.update) {
     mouse.update = false;
     const img = images.getClosest(mouse.x, mouse.y);
     if(img !== lastImage) {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,512,512);
        ctx.drawImage(offScreen,0,0);
        img.draw(ctx);
        lastImage = img;
     }
  }
   requestAnimationFrame(displayLoop);
}


   /* Code below is support code not related directly to the answer */
const mouse = {x : 0, y : 0, update : true};
function mouseEvents(e){
 const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
 mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
  mouse.update = true;
}


function createAllImages(){
   var i = numImages;
   while(i--){ images.add() }
   images.draw(offCtx);
}
function createImage(size, noDraw = false){
  const img = document.createElement("canvas");
  img.width = size;
  img.height = size;  
  if (noDraw) { return img }
  const ctx = img.getContext("2d");
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.fillStyle = "#" + ((0x1000000+(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF | 0)).toString(16).substr(1));
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(size / 2, size / 2, size / 2 - 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
  return img;
}
const image = {
   pos : {x: 0, y: 0},
   img : null,
   init(){
      this.img = createImage(Math.random() * 64 + 64 | 0);
      this.pos ={  x :  Math.random() * canvas.height | 0, y : Math.random() * canvas.width | 0 };
      return this;
   },
   draw(ctx) { ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.pos.x- this.img.width / 2, this.pos.y-this.img.height / 2) },
   distTo(x, y) { return ((x - this.pos.x) ** 2 + (y - this.pos.y) ** 2) ** 0.5 }
}
const images = Object.assign([],{
  add() { this.push({...image}.init()) },
  each(cb) { var index = 0; for(const item of this) { cb(item,index++) } },
  getClosest(x, y) {
    var minDist = Infinity;
    var minIndex = -1;
    this.each((img, i) => {
       const dist = img.distTo(x, y);
       if(dist < minDist){
         minDist = dist;
         minIndex = i;
       }
     });
     return this[minIndex];
  },
  draw(ctx){ this.each(img=>img.draw(ctx)) }
})
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
```